# passing simple pointer with no ownership to boost python

Tags: c++, boost-python, word-wrap

I am moving first steps with `boost python` to test my class but I am facing a difficulty in declaring the python module for my class.

My class accepts a pointer to another class but I don't know how to declare

```
class A{ };

class B
{
    B( std::string& name, A* ptr ){ 
        std::cot << ptr->data << std::endl; // no ownership
    }
    void my_foo(){
        // do something!
    }
};
```

I exported class A to python but I am facing problem with class B

```
class_< B >("B", init< std::string, A >() )
{
    .def("my_foo", &B::my_foo);   
}
```

I am having tons of error. What I am doing wrong?
I am reading about policy but here I don't think I have to apply some of them, am I right?

Kind Regards

AFG

Comment: It probably doesn't know how to extract `A*` from `boost::python::object`. Have you wrapped `A` class?

Comment: It shouldn't compile because the constructor of `B` is private. Post complete code please.

Comment: Hi Maxim. It is been few weeks that I am testing it and I agree with you. THe best way to use boost python is to have proper wrapper in place and having as argument for all functions all basic data ( int,long, std::string, const char * ). It looks that works fine also having const reference to object as arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem with your example is that `boost::python::class_` bodies should not go inside curly braces - they aren't a macro or a new kind of function, they're just template classes with a lot of fancy operator overloading, so what you really want is something like this:

```
class_<B>("B", init<std::string,A*>())
    .def("my_foo", &B::my_foo)
    ;
```

In that snippet, you can see the fix you need for init to compile - just pass `A*` as a template parameter instead of 'A'.  That should be enough to get it to compile.

Whether that's enough for it to do what you want depends on what the constructor for `B` does with the pointer it is passed.  If it simply uses it in the scope of the constructor, or it deep-copies it, you're fine.  But if it holds onto that pointer (e.g. as a data member), then you could run into trouble if the `A` object goes out of scope before the `B` object does.  If that's the case, you would want to use the `with_custodian_and_ward` policy, which I think would look something like this:

```
init<std::string,A*>()[with_custodian_and_ward<1,3>()]
```

The integer template arguments to `with_custodian_and_ward` refer to positional arguments to the `__init__` method; `1` refers to `self`, and `3` refers to the `A*` argument, so this means "keep the `A` object passed to the constructor alive until the constructed `B` object is destroyed."

You can find more information here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/v2/with_custodian_and_ward.html